# onclick event not triggered when onchange triggered right before

Tags: javascript, onclick, onchange

i have a funny problem here.

I have a textarea with an onchange event linked to it.
Then i have a button linked to an onclick event.

The text being put to the textarea is processed when the onchange event gets triggered on the textarea. This normally happens when i click something outside of the textarea.

What i did was the following:

1. I typed in a text into the textarea.
2. Right after typing i click on the button to trigger the onclick event on the button
3. Nothing happens, but the onchange event on the textarea got triggered when i clicked on the button, but the onclick event on the button itself doesnt get triggered.

Why? I expected to get both onchange and onclick triggered. Is there anything i need to do so the click on the button doesnt get "lost". I realized i have to click twice, because first click causes onchange on textarea, and THEN the second click triggers onclick on the button.

The code below shows an exmaple, just try the code below. Type in a text, then directly click on that button. Only the "textarea" popup will come up.

```
<textarea onchange="processText();" name="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="processButton();">Hello</button>
<script language="Javascript">
  function processText()
  {
    alert( 'textarea');
  }

  function processButton()
  {
    alert( 'button');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to show some code that exhibits the problem. How do you expect anyone can tell what the problem is without seeing the code?

Comment: hm looks like this is a bigger problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recheck your assumptions. In your example, *alert()* interrupts the program flow, breaking handling of *onclick*. This code ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/J5kj2/)) demonstrates that *onchange* does not interfere with *onclick* by default:

```
<textarea onchange="processText();" name="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="processButton();">Hello</button>
<div id="clicked"></div>
<div id="changed"></div>
<script language="Javascript">
  function processText()
  {
    document.getElementById('changed').innerHTML = "onchange fired";;
  }

  function processButton()
  {
    document.getElementById('clicked').innerHTML = "onclick fired";
  }
</script>​
```

I had a similar problem, but the actual reason that the *onclick* event was not handled was that the element being clicked, scrolled down as a result of the *onchange* handler. When the mouse button was released, the element did not receive a *mouseup* event and the "click" was interrupted.

Comment: I had the same behavior with the onchange event causing the scroll to shift the clicked button out from under the mouse - thanks Dag.  The only solution I could think of was to delay the scroll to after the mouseup event.

Answer (score 2):

handle onblur event on textarea and onclick event on button

Comment: and how does this help? now onchange and onblur are triggered when i click on the button. when i click on somewhere else, still, onchange and onblur are triggered. i want to catch the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

try this to add event listener to components

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].addEventListener("change", function(){
    alert( 'textarea');
});

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert( 'button');
});
```

if **Ids** are defined then use **getElementById()**.