# Click event not triggered when event is attached to other elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have `onchange` event attached to input text and `onclick` event attached to text link. The click event does not fire when it is clicked after editing the textbox.The change event is fired instead.

The problem is demonstrated [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ak71gscm/1/).

How to handle the click event on the link even after editing the textbox?

Comment: if you make a change, the click somewhere else so that it loses focus and then click on "click me" it works perfect

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a3r7g264/1/ - In chrome I think the alerts are causing the problem.. but otherwise both the handlers are triggered

Comment: That's because so long as the field is in focus, the JavaScript doesn't know whether or not you are done typing.

Comment: The order in which the user will click cannot be assumed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718730/onclick-event-not-triggered-when-onchange-triggered-right-before

Comment: I think the reason is... when the blur happens, since the value is changed onchange event is triggered which shows the modal alert box, so the actual click in the anchor element is not triggered

Answer (score 0):

> Actually when you edit input field and then lost focus from textbox
>   then onChange event is called.

Please understand the scanerio

1. You add some text in input field
2. Now you click on any place instead of textbox
3. alert("changed"); will be called.

> first time when you wil click after editing Textbox definately
>   onchange event will called you can not prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
<a href="javascript:void(0)">click me after editing</a>

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function(){
    alert( 'input field value changed');
});

document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert( 'Link clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your event to `onmousedown`, you'll catch the `click` before the `change` event. Then you can use a variable to prevent change event handler from firing. Like this:

```
//you'll need to declare your variable at the beginning
$(document).ready(function() {
    clicked=false;
});

//reset the variable when clicking on input
<input type= "text" id ="input" onchange='if(!clicked){alert("changed")}' onmousedown='clicked=false'> </input>

//on mousedown gets the click, prevent the change event from firing and fire this handler 
<a onmousedown='clicked=true;alert("hello");'>click me after editing</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eob19qjm/1/